# Custom segue breaks other segues

Tags: ios, segue

I just encountered a strange problem. I have a splash screen that automatically uses a custom segue (fade-to-segue) to go to the home page ViewController. The custom segue works fine, but once it is implemented, my other segues from the home page are no longer working. Pushing the buttons on my home page results in a crash of the app. If I disable the custom segue, my other segues work fine again. The reason for the crash in the debug-window states:

> reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'To
>   Calculator'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller
>   is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

I don't understand what it is saying. Can anyone translate this into plain (and practical) English for me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The message is telling you home page view controller is not in a navigation controller.

Why this is the case I'm not sure.

The storyboard should look something like this:

```
+--------+     +--------+     +--------+
|        |     |        |     |        |
| Splash |--*->|  Nav   |--=->|  Home  |
|        |     |        |     |        |
+--------+     +--------+     +--------+
```

Where `*` is your custom fade-to segue, Nav is a navigation controller, and `=` is the relationship "root view controller" segue.

Comment: This makes sense! My storyboard was set up like this, but the code in my custom segue was interfering with my navigation controller somehow.